# call localhost from express.js app

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I'm creating an express.js app where i call localhost.
simple example:

```
//https://example.com
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
   require('http').request('http://localhost/api/?foo=bar', cb).
       write('foo2=bar2').end();
   resp.render('index');
});
```

my express app run under nginx.
conf:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;

  location /app {
    root   /var/www/node;

    location ~ \.(svg|png|css|js) {
        root /var/www/node/public;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/node/sails.sock;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}

server {

  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  root /var/www/php/htdocs;

  location / {

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param HOST $host;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/php/htdocs$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

I receive a 404 error from http.request('http://localhost/api/?foo=bar'). But from console: curl 'http://localhost/api/?foo=bar' get the right answer. The logs from access.log of nginx are clear. Is it possible to reach localhost in my example? What is wrong?

Comment: `localhost` may be something different to your server than it is for your machine. You may need to call it by its public IP

Comment: @Pekka웃 sure, but want to wind explain of this situation

Comment: Why do you call `.write()` after your request? This is meant to sent a body on for instance a POST call. Your curl would do a GET, that might be the reason for the difference. What happens if you remove the `write('foo2=bar2')` and call `.end()` directly?

Comment: @JasperWoudenberg nothink new. =404